# failed to unregisterReceiver?

Tags: kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I try to unregisterReceiver, but every time call method getTimeDuration, the value of time_duration is not reset even onPause called

value of time_duration is reset every time onPause called

```
class LanFragment : Fragment() {

private var minuteUpdateReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null

private fun startMinuteUpdater() {
    val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)
    minuteUpdateReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            getTimeDuration()
        }
    }
    this.context?.registerReceiver(minuteUpdateReceiver, intentFilter)
}

fun getTimeDuration() {
    time_duration += 1
    Log.d("CheckBroadCast", "getTimeDuration: $time_duration")
    val hour = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(time_duration)
    val minute = time_duration - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hour)
    binding.tvTotalDuration.text = "${hour}h ${minute}m"
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    startMinuteUpdater()
    getTimeDuration()
}

override fun onPause() {
    if (minuteUpdateReceiver != null){
        Log.d("CheckBroadCast", "onPause: ")
        this.context?.unregisterReceiver(minuteUpdateReceiver)
        minuteUpdateReceiver = null
    }
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
}


companion object {
    private var time_duration: Long = 0
}
```

}

or maybe there is method to get same result ? need timecounter as long as activity not destroy